# XML documentation for context sensitive help 

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, document, doxygen, chm

These days a number of commercial and open source tools have been developed for this purpose. However (unfortunately), none of them meet my requirement for a specific problem I am dealing with. Currently, I am working on a project that exposes different classes and functions to a user as a scripting interface. The user can use the objects from the custom scripting interface and call methods to solve some specific problems.

The problem I am facing is that users of my classes need some sort of documentation in order to write their script efficiently. To address this problem I am planing to use the compiler generated XML file to provide context sensitive help, which allows users to mouse over on any of the controls and corresponding methods from the GUI and read the reference documentation of the class/method.

My questions are:

- Can I get the sample source code?
- Can any one advise me how best to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Free Pascal has something similar. It has a separate parser that generates XML abstracts separately, which are the basis for the documentation tool (fpdoc)

The Lazarus IDE can read these XML files in the background, allowing to edit the documentation while editing. It of course can also display already entered information. (though more in a wiki-like makeup, not rendered)